# React js + Node js + Electron + exe file for Desktop APP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, npm-install, electron-builder

I am just creating **electron desktop app**. Initially I have configure **react js with electron**, then I have converted it into **.exe file**. After that I have faced lot of challenge to add **node js app inside exe file for production build**. I can't go with online server setup, as this is a **offline desktop app**. So I have **published my node js app into npm package then install that package in my react app to serve RestAPI**. Everything working perfectly in both dev and production.

I am just worrying about **security issues**. Can you please let me know it is good to go for live or is there any alternate solutions?. Also please advice about **disadvantage of making our server app into npm package**.

I have do research on this, but not able to find any related docs. That's why I came here. Thanks for your time.

I am ready to share my config source codes. Please feel free to ask